Multi Container Azure App Service (How to connect to a specific container)
I have a Web App multi-container in Azure using Compose, and there are several containers running in it. Does anyone know how to connect to a specific container, or has Microsoft not added this feature for multi-container applications yet?
My application has some containers. Every container has port 2222 open, but through standard SSH, only Nginx can be accessed since it is the main one that uses port 80. I haven't found any useful information on how to get around this. I saw that a couple of years ago, Microsoft mentioned that the feature was not yet available for multi-container apps, but they planned to add it. Perhaps someone has encountered this problem....
My deployment config for multi-container:
 services:
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: test.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - worker
      - beat
      - flower
    command: /start-nginx.sh
    ports: 
      - '2222:2222'
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: test.azurecr.io/backend:latest
    command: /start-django
    ports: 
      - '81:81'
  worker:
    container_name: celery-worker
    image: test.azurecr.io/backend:latest
    command: /start-celeryworker
  beat:
    container_name: celery-beat
    image: test.azurecr.io/backend:latest
    command: /start-celerybeat
  flower:
    container_name: celery-flower
    image: test.azurecr.io/backend:latest
    command: /start-flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"

My nginx conf for this:
server {

listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location /api/v1 {
  auth_basic off;

  proxy_pass http://backend:81;
  proxy_set_header  Host                $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
}

location /admin {
  auth_basic off;

  proxy_pass http://backend:81;
  proxy_set_header  Host                $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
}

location /flower {
  auth_basic off;

  proxy_pass http://flower:5555/flower/;
  proxy_set_header  Host          $host;
  proxy_set_header  Upgrade       $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header  Connection    "upgrade";
}

location / {
    auth_basic off;

    root /var/static;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

}
Maybe someone has found a solution on how to get into a certain container? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!
